# Pop up button not showing in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, popup

I am currently trying to make a pop up form and for some reason my form just return me blank. I am currently following [this website](https://www.formget.com/how-to-create-pop-up-contact-form-using-javascript/).

When I go look at view page source, all the codes are still there, but nothing is showing in the blade. It is just blank. There is suppose to be pop up button showing

Here is my blade:

evaltest.blade.php

```
 <html>
    <head> 
        <title>Popup contact form </title>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">    
        <link href="{{ asset('css/elements.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/my_js.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-43981329-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        (function () {
        var ga = document.createElement('script');
        ga.type = 'text/javascript';
        ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>
    </head> 
     <!-- body starts here -->
     <body id ="bdy" style="overflow:hidden;">

     <div id="abc">

         <!-- Popup div starts here -->
     <div id="popupContact"> 

        <!-- contact us form -->
             <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/evaltest/'.$data->id) }}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
             <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{$data->id}}">

         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2"><b>Recommendation:</b></label>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="radio" id ="recommendation" name="recommendation" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
            <input type="radio" id ="recommendation" name="recommendation" value="No"> No<br>
          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2"><b>Training Schedule:</b></label>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="radio" id = "training_schedule" name="training_schedule" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
            <input type="radio" id = "training_schedule" name="training_schedule" value="No"> No<br>
            <input type="radio" id = "training_schedule" name="training_schedule" value="NIL"> NIL<br>
          </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2"><b>Training Date (key in date if yes or pending, else just say nil and leave the date):</b></label>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="date" id = "training_date" name="training_date" class="form-control">
            <input type="text" id = "training_date" name="training_date" class="form-control">
          </div>        
                <a id="submit" href="javascript: check_empty()">Send</a>
            </form>
     </div> 
    <!-- Popup Div Ends Here -->
    </div>
    <!-- Display Popup Button -->
    <h1>Click Button To Popup Form Using Javascript</h1>
    <button id="popup" onclick="div_show()">Popup</button>
    </body>
    <!-- Body Ends Here -->
    </html>
```

Here is the controller I am using:

```
     public function getEval1(){
       $data = personal_info::whereDoesntHave('evaluations')->first();
       if(count($data)>0){
        return view('evaltest',compact('data'));
    }else{
    return view('evaltest');
}
```

Here are the routes: (if needed)

```
Route::get('/user/showupdate8/{id}/evaltest', 'evalController@getEval1');
Route::post('/evaltest/{id}', 'evalController@eval');
```

And also for the JavaScript and CSS, I just copy and paste from the website so there won't be any difference. But for the JavaScript, I only replaced their id with mine while the rest remains the same.

Comment: I have stored both my css and js inside my public folder already, so shouldn't it work? Or am I really suppose to set the permission to 777 for it to work?

Comment: Does browsers developer console shows any errors?

Comment: @Vishal wait there is an error which says, Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: What's inside div_show() js function?

Comment: But i did put the path correctly for the javascript as shown in my evaltest.blade.php. I kept the js inside the public folder

Comment: I am unsure of that as well, I am not really good with js so I am not really sure what to do

Comment: Why aren't you declaring path the way you declared for css file?

Comment: @Vishal Do you mean this? function div_show() {
document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "block";
}

Comment: What do you mean? My js is saved under public/js while css is under public/css

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158665/discussion-between-vishal-and-dkna).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First correct your js inclusion code

```
<script src="{{ asset('/js/my_js.js) }}"></script>
```

It will be good if you include js code in the footer area of the webpage.